# Database Migration (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day, I have developed a system using php and mysql. From 5 systems turned into 1 system. Basically, there is a huge possibility that in system 1 there will be a user table and has primary keys. The same with other systems.

My problem is there are identical primary ids to be migrated in current developed system.
In system 1, there are 70,000 data in user table. System 2, 22,000 records. and less than 3000 in other systems. Unfortunately, primary keys were foreign keys in other tables.

How can I migrate those data without conflict in primary keys and how can I update foreign keys?

Please help.

Comment: You could add a column `source_system` in each table and build the unique keys over both the current ID column and that new one. Or you have to migrate and use new IDs

Comment: Thanks @Nico What I did, temporarily, I generated a new id.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a mapping between the various user records and the new consolidated user master table. Pls note that this may be true not only for the users, but also for other type of data as well.

When you create the mapping table, then have a new user id field, an old user id field and a field identifying the source system. Then copy over the users by source system to the mapping table and during the copy specify the source system. This way you can distinguish between the users with the same user ids in the various source systems and generate the new user ids.

When you migrate other data from the source systems containing user id, you need to use the mapping table to replace the old user ids with the new one.